The position of Adverb of manner and the complement
Prepare well for this.
Verb+ Adv+ Comp
Prepare for this well.
Verb+  Comp+ Adv
The first is no doubt right. But, is the second one incorrect? Isn't it understandable? If we place the complement before the Adv of manner, is that an error?

Both are fine. If you have time, you could read through dozens of questions on adverb position here.

Both are correct and in this case in makes no difference which you use. They have a slightly different nuance, "Prepare well, and it is this that you are preparing for" versus "Prepare for this and do it well". There may seem be some sentences where the difference matters, but not this one.

To emphasize @timchessish’s point, your first example feels a bit as though it were answering a question like “For what is it important that I prepare well?” while the second might answer the question, “How thoroughly should I prepare for this?”
